# 2nd derivative test , Maximum point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A study shows that a human body reaction R to a dosage D of a certain drug is given by

$$ R = D^2(\frac{k}{2} - \frac{D}{3}) $$

Show that he rate of change in the reaction $R$ with respect to the dosage $D$ is maximum if $D = K/2 $

My first derivative is

$R' = KD - D^2 $,

Dosage for maximum reaction = $k$

My second derivative is

$R''= K - 2D $

$R(\frac{k}{2}) = k - 2(\frac{k}{2}) = 0 $

But 0 is neither negative or positive , how do I show that it's a maximum (negative) ?

Comment: Where does the $k/2$ come from (after the line $R'' = \ldots$)?

Comment: You are trying to show that the first derivative reaches a maximum at $\frac{k}{2}$, so solving the second derivative only gives critical point for the maximum, which you verified to be as $\frac{k}{2}$. To show that this is a maximum, you can take two different approaches: 1. Show that $D<\frac{k}{2}\Rightarrow R''>0$ and $D>\frac{k}{2}\Rightarrow R''<0$ 2. Take the second derivative of $R'$, which is $R'''$, and show that it is negative at $\frac{k}{2}$

Comment: @Gribouillis It came from setting $K-2D=0$ and solving.

Comment: @Hushus46 I understand, the question is *where is the maximum of* $R'$ ?

Comment: @Gribouillis To find the maximum of $R'$, you must take its derivative, i.e $R''$, and solve it to find the critical point of $R'$. Then you apply the second derivative test to $R'$ and this critical point to show that is a maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you are confused with what the question being asked is. It wants you to show that the rate of change, $R'$, (not $R$) achieves a maximum at $\frac{k}{2}$.

By setting $R''=0$, you have shown that there is a critical point at $\frac{k}{2}$, now you only have to show that it is a maximum.

I will take the approach of the second derivative test as you mentioned in the title.

We must find the second derivative of $R'$, namely, $R'''$.

$R'''=\frac{d}{dD}(R'')=\frac{d}{dD}(K-2D)=-2.$

Since $R'''$, the second derivative of $R'$, is negative regardless of what $D$ is, then $D= \frac{k}{2}$ which we found as the only critical point is a maximum.

Comment: How do u infer that the question is asking for second derivative of R' ? Because my first instinct was to find Second derivative of R

Comment: @user307640 It says "Show that the rate of change in the reaction R ... is maximum...". When I see that they are asking to show something about "rate of change" I immediately know they are asking to find the maximum of the rate of change, which is R'. If it makes it any more intuitive, you can just represent $R'$ as a new function, lets say, $R'=Q(D)$ and show that $\frac{k}{2}$ is a maximum of $Q(D)$ instead of going to the third derivative of $R$.

Comment: alright ! Got it . Thanks a lot

Comment: @user307640 No problem, make sure to mark either quasi's or my answer, whichever you feel suits your needs, as correct so that this post can be complete.

Answer (score 3):

Use the first derivative test on $R'$. It's immediate that $R''>0$ when $D < k/2$, and $R''<0$ when $D>k/2$. Thus, since $R''(k/2)=0$, it follows that $R'$ has a local maximum at $D=k/2$. But since there's only one critical point, it follows that the local maximum is, in fact, a global maximum.

However, if you prefer, you *can* use the second derivative test. The second derivative of $R'$ is $R'''$ which is identically $-2$. In particular, $R'''(k/2)<0$, hence, since $R''(k/2)=0$, it follows that $R'$ has a local maximum at $D=k/2$. But once again, since there's only one critical point, it follows that the local maximum is, in fact, a global maximum.

An even simpler approach is to note that $R'$ is a quadratic function of $D$ with negative leading coefficient, hence the critical value for $R'$ (i.e., $D=k/2)$ is where $R'$ attains a global maximum.

Comment: The question is asking to show that the rate of change is maximum at $\frac{k}{2}$, not that the original function is maximum at that point.

Comment: Oh, Ok -- will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

D = k or 0 (don't miss the 0 solution!) satisfy the first-order condition; beware that this doesn't guarantee max/min yet (i.e. FOC is just a necessary condition).  So don't jump to any conclusion at this stage.

k/2 doesn't satisfy FOC, so it definitely isn't a max/min.

FYI, if some day you encounter a 0 when checking the second order condition, it means the FOC solutions may be max/min/a saddle point.  Essentially, you can't infer anything from the second-order test.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are incorrect. The question is asking to show that $\frac{k}{2}$ is a maximum for $R'$ (the rate of change).